# Set specific font for bold text in Angular Material

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, scss-mixins, angular-material-9

I'm using two custom fonts in my Angular application, one for normal text and one for bold text. I want to shift towards Angular Material, but I can't figure out how to set the bold font in it.

This is how I set my custom font in `styles.scss`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: CustomFont;
  src: url(assets/font.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: CustomBoldFont;
  src: url(assets/font-bold.ttf) format("truetype");
}
    
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'CustomFont, sans-serif'
);

@include mat-base-typography($custom-typography);
```

How do I tell Angular Material to use `CustomBoldFont` in e.g. h1-h6, b, th, etc? I tried setting my own rules but they are overridden.

Comment: Hey @Peter! I have added my suggestions but if you still face the issue, would you be able to share stackblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply `mat-typography` class to parent of element on which you want your custom typography to be applied.

Excerpt from [official typography guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography):
By default, Angular Material doesn't apply any global CSS. To apply the library's typographic styles more broadly, you can take advantage of the mat-typography CSS class. This class will style all descendant native elements.

```
<!-- By default, Angular Material applies no global styles to native elements. -->
<h1>This header is unstyled</h1>

<!-- Applying the mat-tyography class adds styles for native elements. -->
<section class="mat-typography">
  <h1>This header will be styled</h1>
</section>
```

if that still doesn't work, most likely an issue is with the way you are adding font-family, try if following works:

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"CustomFont", sans-serif'
);
```

Comment: Angular Material marked the body element with mat-typography by default. I've tried the ' "CustomFont' " trick but did not work. If I inspect the h1 it says calculated: font: 400 24px/32px CustomFont,sans-serif; which should be bold, however it's not. If I explicitly add font-weight: bold it becomes bold. I didn't have this issue with the default Roboto font.

Comment: interesting, would you be able to share mvp?

Comment: Ok so I changed the @font-face directive's font-weight attribute from bold to 400 and it works now...strikethrough this, now everything is bold. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url("assets/font.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url("assets/font-bold.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but does not work, still everything is non-bold. If I remove the non-bold @font-face declaration, the h1 tag becomes bold as intended, and normal text does not become bold, BUT the normal text is Arial.